# MySQL Many to Many Grouping

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following tables with these attributes:

**location** - location_id, name

**schedule** - schedule_id, name

**locatoin_schedule** - location_id, schedule_id

I am using a query like this.

```
SELECT l.name as locationName, s.name as scheduleName
FROM location AS l, schedule AS s, location_schedule AS ls
WHERE ls.schedule_id = s.schedule_id
AND ls.location_id = l.location_id
```

This is returning an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [locationName] => testing
            [scheduleName] => New Schedule
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [locationName] => another
            [scheduleName] => New Schedule
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [locationName] => testing
            [scheduleName] => Another Schedule
        )

)
```

Is it possible to have this return a multidimensional array of schedules if a location has many schedules as is the case with the `testing` location? So my intended outcome will be an array with only 2 indexes, rather than 3... but the testing locationName will contain an array with two schedules.

I hope this makes sense, thanks for your answer.

Comment: It depends on how the query results are being pulled into PHP. MySQL is not directly returning anything into a php array - it's returning a grid result of columns and rows, and your PHP code is putting it into the array you illustrated. Post that code. (i.e. mysql_fetch_object(), etc)

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html - I am using codeigniter and the code is $query = $this->db->query('SELECT name, title, email FROM my_table'); so it just returns the rows returned from mysql and converts that to an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're stuck either processing the current query into the datastructure you want, or using GROUP_CONCAT and then splitting the schedules string into the structure you want.  I'd stick with the first because it's cleaner and the query is faster.

```
$q="
SELECT l.name as locationName, s.name as scheduleName 
FROM location AS l JOIN schedule AS s ON ls.schedule_id = s.schedule_id 
 JOIN location_schedule AS ls
  ON ls.location_id = l.location_id";
$r=$db->query($q)
while($arr=$r->fetch_assoc()){
  $data[$arr['locationName']][]=$arr['scheduleName'];
}
```

or the GROUP_CONCAT option:

```
$q="
SELECT l.name as locationName, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) as scheduleName 
FROM location AS l JOIN schedule AS s ON ls.schedule_id = s.schedule_id 
 JOIN location_schedule AS ls
  ON ls.location_id = l.location_id
GROUP BY locationName";
$r=$db->query($q)
while($arr=$r->fetch_assoc()){
  $schedules=explode($arr['scheduleName']);
  $data[$arr['locationName']]=$schedules
}
```